# Is there a way to consume payloads from kafka without using @Incoming (Quarkus, smallrye, kafka)?

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I'm creating a publish method using Emitter<>
And I'm trying to create a unit test for this method.
I don't want to use the InMemoryConnector (as described in the quarkus doc)
I want to use the actual kafka connector configured in my application.yaml (mp:
messaging:
outgoing:
:
connector: smallrye-kafka)

So I'm trying to create a consumer in my test class to consume data from the kafka broker.
That's why I don't want to use the @Incoming annotation.
Is there on other way to consume data from the kafka ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [Kafka Companion test library](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#testing-using-a-kafka-broker) which is easy to integrate into Quarkus tests. It provides a convenient API to produce and consume records from the Kafka broker and write assertions against consumed records.